# "Error: Invocation of form set() doesn't match definition set(object items, optional function callback)"

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, local-storage

i have a gmail extension which uses ,
`chrome.storage.local.set` methods in content script.
it works well for extension, but when extension off and the on or extension not uses for a long time and then uses , it shows an error like

"Error: Invocation of form set() doesn't match definition set(object items, optional function callback)"

for the code

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'loggedinUser':  $('.gb_Fb').html() });
```

when the page reloads it again works well. I need a solution to work this without page reload

Edit: i added the below code in background.js asper @wOxxOm, but it still shows the same error

```
var manifest = chrome.app.getDetails();
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
  windows.forEach(function(window){
    window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
        var url = tab.url; 
        if(url.indexOf('https://mail.google.com') > -1){ 
             var  scripts= manifest.content_scripts[0].js;  
             s = scripts.length;  
            for(var k = 0 ; k < s; k++ ) {  
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: scripts[k]
              });
            }
        }

    });
  });
});
```

also the listner in content script

```
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function doListen(request){
        chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(doListen);
        if (request.data && request.types && request.types =='MESSAGE_COMPOSE') {
            window.postMessage({ type: "MESSAGE_COMPOSE",email:request.data}, "*");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: When the extension is disabled, its content script is orphaned. I guess you're using onMessage listener. You need to give a name to the listener function and unregister it inside the listener when some condition is met, for example `if (!chrome.i18n)` And of course your background script will have to run your content script explicitly via chrome.tabs.executeScript when re-enabled. You can find an existing answer here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, please see my edit on question

Comment: You're removing onRequest, which is unrelated here. Also, you probably need a condition because currently you'll receive the message just once.

Comment: @wOxxOm,sorry  idon't understand, how do i unregister the listner then?

Comment: Uhm... use onMessage, not onRequest? Also, without seeing the relevant code where the error occurs this is far as I can help.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't use `chrome.storage.local.set`.

Comment: hi @Teepeemm, code added. error shows for this code
 `chrome.storage.local.set({ 'loggedinUser':  $('.gb_Fb').html() });`

Comment: HI @wOxxOm, can you please explain solution, i didn't get any solution yet